# iframe store in variable and append it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, flowplayer

My bootstrap modal play a video that loads in a iframe.
Now i want  to make my iframe data null first when click modal close button then insert a iframe from background on this iframe

my code

```
$('#abc_55').on('hide', function () {

var newSrc="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k";

document.getElementById("preview-frame").src='';
document.getElementById("preview-frame").src=newSrc;
});
```

But its not work

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you want to insert something into a closed modal?

Comment: cause when close then src will be empty the if i click video thumb then src will be empty @DesignbyAdrian

Comment: why not modifying src when modal is shown, instead of the other way around?

Comment: try .src="about:blank" instead if .src="" . It will load an empty page instead of showing the current directory. If that isn't the problem you are experiencing, you need to explain in more detail. If you only want to change the src when the frame isn't hidden, you could use a variable and if statement to do that??